# Calculating determinant from LUDecomposition

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, mathematica

As far as i know LU decomposition allow you to calculate matrix determinant following easy and cheap formula: Det[A] = Det[L] Det[U] = Det[U]

Trying this out in Mathematica 7 gives me correct result by absolute value, i.e. it ignores negative determinants and transforms them to positive ones.

Sample code:

```
matrixA = {{-1, 2, 3, 5}, {-7, -4, 5, 4}, {-89, 7, 8, -6}, {8, 6, -1, 4}};
```

`Det[matrixA]` gives out -2067

but

```
{lu, p, c} = LUDecomposition[matrixA]

u = lu SparseArray[{i_, j_} /; j >= i -> 1, {4, 4}]
```

`Det[u]` is 2067

Well, the question is obvious - how to get correct determinant in Mathematica using LU decomposition?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, this is because you forgot to take into account the *permutation matrix* that is output by the LU decomposition routine. You have to remember two facts: 1.) Gaussian elimination generally performs row interchanges for numerical stability reasons, and 2.) the determinant of a matrix changes sign if you interchange rows.

In *Mathematica* at least, the function that will rescue you is `Signature[]`, which gives the signature of the permutation required to turn the permutation matrix (which *Mathematica* outputs as a scrambled list of the numbers from 1 to n, where n is the size of your matrix) into the identity matrix.

So, to use your example in *Mathematica*:

```
m={{-1, 2, 3, 5}, {-7, -4, 5, 4}, {-89, 7, 8, -6}, {8, 6, -1, 4}};
```

we compare

```
Det[m]
-2067
```

with the following:

```
{lu, p, c} = LUDecomposition[m]
{{{-1, 2, 3, 5}, {7, -18, -16, -31}, {-8, -11/9, 31/9, 55/9}, {89, 19/2, -963/31, 2067/62}}, {1, 2, 4, 3}, 1}
```

Now, `LUDecomposition[]` here outputs three things: the merged $\mathbf{L}$ and $\mathbf{U}$ matrices, the permutation, and the condition number. We can get the tentative determinant by multiplying together the diagonal elements of `lu`, thus:

```
Tr[lu, Times]
2067
```

Here is where `Signature` comes in:

```
Signature[{1, 2, 4, 3}]
-1
```

Note that to turn `{1, 2, 4, 3}` into `{1, 2, 3, 4}`, one needs one swap; namely, to swap the third and fourth elements. Since 1 is odd, the signature is -1.

Thus,

```
Signature[p]*Tr[lu, Times]
-2067
```

gives the correct answer.

Comment: Very clear and through answer - kudos!

Answer (score 3):

From the documentation: "Therefore multiplying L and U recreates the original matrix permuted with the row pivot vector." So you need to multiply by `Signature[p]` to get the correct sign.

Comment: You beat me! No worries, +1!

Comment: @J. M.: No wonder I was quicker, since your answer was a _liiiiitle_ bit more ambitious!